# Make KeepassX float in i3wm

Tags: configuration, i3, tiling-wm

I want to start keepassX in floating mode in i3wm. my `.config/i3/config` contains the line

```
 for_window [class="keepassx"] floating enable
```

and the xprop

```
xprop 
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 7578932
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 29360143
_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) =    Icon (64 x 64):


XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "myKeys.kdbx - KeePassX"
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1c00005
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 26787
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x3, 0x3e, 0x7e, 0x0, 0x0
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Keys.kdbx - KeePassX"
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "keepassx", "Keepassx"
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: True
        Initial state is Normal State.
        bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x1c0000b
        window id # of group leader: 0x1c00005
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        user specified location: 960, 22
        program specified location: 960, 22
        user specified size: 956 by 1033
        program specified size: 956 by 1033
        program specified minimum size: 640 by 517
        window gravity: NorthWest
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "nautilus"
WM_COMMAND(STRING) = { "keepassx" }
```

I also tried the command

```
  for_window [instance="keepassx"] floating enable
```

how can I make the keepassX always stars in floating mode?

Comment: Your class criterion does not work because *i3* does case-sensitive matches. and the first value of `WM_CLASS` is actually the instance, while the second value is the class. That means that the second attempt with `instance` instead of `class` should work and actually does so on my Arch+i3 installation. Could there be other `for_window` rules that actively disable floating mode in your configuration?

Comment: If it doesn't solve your problem, you may consider posting your i3wm config. (per pastebin or something alike)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adaephon said, you just looked at the wrong string. Everything else should be fine.

You want to distinct by class, so let's look at your xprop:

`WM_CLASS(STRING) = "keepassx", "Keepassx"`

This line is defined like:

`WM_CLASS(STRING) = instance, class`

As you see, you wanted to float `keepassx`, but the class is `Keepassx`

There are two solutions for you:

1. Use `for_window [class="Keepassx"] floating enable`, as this refers to the right class name.
2. Use `for_window [class="(?i)keepassx"] floating enable`, which means that the searched string will be case-**un**sensitive.

Bear in mind, that you can also use `for_window` with other attributes, like `name`, `instance`, etc.

EDIT: I've read his comment again and yes, he should be right: Look again at your config to strike out that *after* that line, another one comes that may disable floating mode for specific or every windows.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I tried both. your first suggestion and the hint from @Adaephon. Suddenly it worked it might be that I used the wrong key combination to restart i3. Sorry

Comment: Don't worry. I use i3 now for about a month and write new stuff into my config every few days and still make these mistakes. :-)